# Is it possible to convert the below collection to array as shown in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Currently have generated the below result by dynamic key and value using `$arrayToObject` in mongodb.

```
[
  {
    "ACCOUNT1": "test1"
  },
  {
    "ACCOUNT2": "test2"
  },
  {
    "ACCOUNT3": "test3"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to convert the above collection as shown below in mongodb

```
{
   "ACCOUNT1": "test1",
   "ACCOUNT2": "test2",
   "ACCOUNT3": "test3"
}
```

Comment: your expected result is not valid JSON.

Comment: @turivishal got it. Edited the output.

Comment: I guess you are trying to say `{  "ACCOUNT1": "test1", "ACCOUNT2": "test2", "ACCOUNT3": "test3" }`. please post your try anything you researched on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation query,

- `$mergeObjects` to merge object documents properties
- `$group` by null and merge root documents using the above operation
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above grouped document to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u450ov9cfEg)

Comment: Thanks. Got the output as array with size as one.